# Removing html tags in cURL

Tags: php, html, curl

I'm trying to get the contents of a url in the form of plain text. Currently i've managed to get all the HTML content from the url. I want to know if it's possible to remove html tags in cURL.

```
 <?php
    // put your code here
    $ch = curl_init();
    $url = "http://visitbirmingham.com/explore-birmingham/blog";
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5);
    $cResult = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    $cResult = str_replace("<", "&lt;", $cResult);
    $cResult = str_replace(">", "&gt;", $cResult);

    echo  $cResult;

    ?>
```

Comment: Wow, google _php remove html tags_ is amazing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out the php function [`strip_tags`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php).

```
echo strip_tags($cResult);
```